# How to fetch a particular pattern using regular expression in Robot Framework?

Tags: regex, robotframework

I have a scenario where I need to fetch a particular pattern from the string using regular expression.

The string looks like below:

```
${text} = Slot 0   l  5  3  24+6 
          Slot 1   l  3 16  10
          Slot 3   l  4  3  32
          Slot 8   l  2  3 
          Slot 9   l  1  3
```

Here, I need to fetch only

`Slot 0
 Slot 1
 Slot 3
 Slot 8
 Slot 9`

How do I do this?

I have tried using the keywords 'Replace String Using Regexp' and 'Get Regexp Matches' for the same.

```
${text}=  String.Replace String Using Regexp  ${response}   [^Slot\\s+\\d], ${EMPTY}
```

The result was:

```
${text} = Slot 0 l 5 3 24+6 Slot 1 l 3 16 10 Slot 3 l 4 3 32 Slot 8 l 2 3 Slot 9 l 1 3 –
```

And, `Get Regexp Matches` gives the below result:

```
${matches}=   String.Get Regexp Matches  ${response}    [Slot\\s+\\d]
```

The result:

```
${matches}=   ['S', 'l', 'o', 't', ' ', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'l', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '5', ' ', '3', ' ', ' ', '2', '4', '+', '6', '\r', '\n', 'S', 'l', 'o', 't', ' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'l', ' ', ' ... –
```

Comment: What have you tried, show the effort you've put in solving it yourself. Don't just expect it'll be solved by someone else for you - the community will help and guide, but the purpose is hardly doing something instead of you. I'd recommend using this site trying out the different options - https://regex101.com , select the python flavor in it.

Comment: I have tried in number of ways. I have also used http://pythex.org/ also for this. When I have not found the solution for this, I wanted to know if there is some one who can have a solution for it.

Comment: You're on the right track, but spin it otherwise - use the keyword [Get Regexp Matches](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Regexp%20Matches) to get just the substrings you're interested in; the regexp is also ok, just don't negate it like in your removal approach. And add your comment, plus any further results in the question's body ;)

Comment: In your second attempt, remove the square brackets, and you're there! From regex101 hints - `[] Matches a single character from the list` - you don't need that, you want a match on the whole substring.

Comment: Please delete your `KEYWORD` comments (they are fairly unreadable) and add them into the question via the edit feature, thanks.

Comment: Is this working now?

Comment: Thanks @Todor it worked for me.

Comment: The code at the top of your question is invalid robot syntax. Can you please post some actual code?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is just to remove the square brackets used for the regular expression in **'Get Regexp Matches'** keyword.

i.e., Use **Slot\s+\d+**  instead of **[Slot\s+\d+]**

This is because [] Matches a single character from the list and my requirement was to fetch the whole substring.

**Thanks @Todor**